# clipboardData: Prevent Chrome to create new DIV,P

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, clipboarddata

I'm pasting HTML to contentEditable div, In DIV there is p tag which contains default text as a placeholder.

When I am pasting multi-line text, Google chrome creates `<p>` tags for each new line text.

```
rotate_div.addEventListener("paste", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var text = e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");
        document.execCommand("insertText", false, text);
    });
```

This works fine in Firefox but due to new `DIV` it's showing in one line.

I want to replace new line character with `<br>`.

## OR

Is there anything that I can prevent new DIV on paste ?

Comment: use regular expressions to find and replace

Comment: but what to search for ? I have tried replacing `\r\n` with `<br>`.

Comment: Instead of div use textarea
see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fmowh1ev/ if it is of some help.
Can you provide with some demo fiddle?